# OpenCV fileStorage XML format - how to write and read multiple structures of the same type in one file

Tags: c++, xml, opencv

I am trying to implement writing multiple values to a XML file using OpenCV library.

I am trying to save one of the structures which I use in my project:

```
if (validCalib)
{ 
    QString calpath = path() + "/" + "calibration.xml"; 

    for (int i = 0; i < calibrations_.size(); ++i) 
    {
        QLOGX(" Writing calibration no. " << i); 
        calibrations_[i]->append(calpath.toStdString()); 
        xml.writeTextElement(XML_CALIBSTRUCT, calpath); 
    } 
}
```

The line `calibrations_[i]->append(calpath.toStdString());` is a wrapper around the following code:

```
void Calibration3D::append(const std::string &path) const
{
LOGX("Storing calibration in: '" << path << "'");

cv::FileStorage fsCal(path, cv::FileStorage::APPEND);
fsCal << "imgSizeW" << imgSize_.width;
fsCal << "imgSizeH" << imgSize_.height;
fsCal << "error" << error_;

fsCal << "cam1M" << cam1_.camera_;
fsCal << "dist1M" << cam1_.distort_;
fsCal << "cam1Err" << cam1_.error_;
fsCal << "cam2M" << cam2_.camera_;
fsCal << "dist2M" << cam2_.distort_;
fsCal << "cam2Err" << cam2_.error_;

fsCal << "rot" << rot_;
fsCal << "trans" << trans_;
fsCal << "ess" << ess_;
fsCal << "fund" << fund_;
}
```

It generates a following file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<opencv_storage>
<imgSizeW>1624</imgSizeW>
<imgSizeH>1232</imgSizeH>
<error>1.0434992866920401e-001</error>
<cam1M type_id="opencv-matrix">
  <rows>3</rows>
  <cols>3</cols>
  <dt>d</dt>
  <data>
    5.8336770199129896e+003 0. 7.9461884987678354e+002 0.
    5.8346113022077216e+003 6.2767580661716852e+002 0. 0. 1.</data></cam1M>
<dist1M type_id="opencv-matrix">
  <rows>1</rows>
  <cols>5</cols>
  <dt>d</dt>
  <data>
    -4.1521842761754475e-002 -1.2257987732483255e+000
    1.8424136500047315e-003 -1.3132630808037672e-003 0.</data></dist1M>
<cam1Err>9.9465113482762754e-002</cam1Err>
<cam2M type_id="opencv-matrix">
  <rows>3</rows>
  <cols>3</cols>
  <dt>d</dt>
  <data>
    5.8076598763871389e+003 0. 8.1187260416598792e+002 0.
    5.8094240172010641e+003 6.3986386929850755e+002 0. 0. 1.</data></cam2M>
<dist2M type_id="opencv-matrix">
  <rows>1</rows>
  <cols>5</cols>
  <dt>d</dt>
  <data>
    -9.2121454522962165e-002 1.8926990233429226e+000
    1.7827799056532767e-003 -5.5230657283086685e-004 0.</data></dist2M>
<cam2Err>1.0166116306730072e-001</cam2Err>
<rot type_id="opencv-matrix">
  <rows>3</rows>
  <cols>3</cols>
  <dt>d</dt>
  <data>
    8.4241672981065119e-001 -5.8573511631213023e-003
    -5.3879471487058994e-001 1.0809897944575920e-002
    9.9992338290376193e-001 6.0311216804594652e-003
    5.3871810758647809e-001 -1.0905033683970737e-002
    8.4241550365528961e-001</data></rot>
<trans type_id="opencv-matrix">
  <rows>3</rows>
  <cols>1</cols>
  <dt>d</dt>
  <data>
    5.0365870692993354e+002 -5.1969545995371860e+000
    1.3064843970613484e+002</data></trans>
<ess type_id="opencv-matrix">
  <rows>3</rows>
  <cols>3</cols>
  <dt>d</dt>
  <data>
    -4.2119898469169144e+000 -1.3058175683709450e+002
    -5.1659517636726635e+000 -1.6126963413464023e+002
    4.7271613740233587e+000 -4.9468259208850623e+002
    9.8225007195261931e+000 5.0358967767424525e+002
    2.3753527526426321e-001</data></ess>
<fund type_id="opencv-matrix">
  <rows>3</rows>
  <cols>3</cols>
  <dt>d</dt>
  <data>
    2.7779018317104696e-008 8.6107808772984268e-007
    -3.6379467295147945e-004 1.0632864450905678e-006
    -3.1162232035265673e-008 1.8201493171578327e-002
    -1.0791410825328929e-003 -1.9964962350893754e-002 1.</data></fund>
 <!-- resumed -->

<imgSizeW>1624</imgSizeW>
<imgSizeH>1232</imgSizeH>
<error>7.4143478139918727e+001</error>
<cam1M type_id="opencv-matrix">
  <rows>3</rows>
  <cols>3</cols>
  <dt>d</dt>
  <data>
    4.5249661359074507e+003 0. 3.8802378752536885e+002 0.
    4.7322013075897985e+003 -4.6265793355141220e+001 0. 0. 1.</data></cam1M>
<dist1M type_id="opencv-matrix">
  <rows>1</rows>
  <cols>5</cols>
  <dt>d</dt>
  <data>
    4.9921668140553797e+000 -3.9127832752862915e+001
    -1.2848597924228053e-001 5.1729958527179563e-002 0.</data></dist1M>
<cam1Err>9.9465117306014511e-002</cam1Err>
<cam2M type_id="opencv-matrix">
  <rows>3</rows>
  <cols>3</cols>
  <dt>d</dt>
  <data>
    4.0809201332391053e+003 0. -2.5863160533898072e+003 0.
    5.5465207503753049e+002 -1.0031409700981827e+001 0. 0. 1.</data></cam2M>
<dist2M type_id="opencv-matrix">
  <rows>1</rows>
  <cols>5</cols>
  <dt>d</dt>
  <data>
    2.1904296242925554e+000 -3.9306686802274299e-001
    1.8437752313918845e-001 -6.1134319745319177e-001 0.</data></dist2M>
<cam2Err>1.0166116351399195e-001</cam2Err>
<rot type_id="opencv-matrix">
  <rows>3</rows>
  <cols>3</cols>
  <dt>d</dt>
  <data>
    7.8478700811122082e-001 -3.2115568696367880e-001
    -5.3006450233035418e-001 3.5509697225959491e-001
    9.3396756794800728e-001 -4.0133805119286346e-002
    5.0795225385060261e-001 -1.5672781103611425e-001
    8.4700702538758266e-001</data></rot>
<trans type_id="opencv-matrix">
  <rows>3</rows>
  <cols>1</cols>
  <dt>d</dt>
  <data>
    1.8785463165085166e+003 1.2890651672036026e+002
    -1.3964346923814824e+003</data></trans>
<ess type_id="opencv-matrix">
  <rows>3</rows>
  <cols>3</cols>
  <dt>d</dt>
  <data>
    5.6134808692706054e+002 1.2840214772478846e+003
    5.3140487474538034e+001 -2.0501156396900251e+003
    7.4289339504802365e+002 -8.5094146734464744e+002
    5.6590194965857836e+002 1.7959003954385691e+003
    -7.0644431417887716e+000</data></ess>
<fund type_id="opencv-matrix">
  <rows>3</rows>
  <cols>3</cols>
  <dt>d</dt>
  <data>
    -7.7975382126785714e-007 -1.7054919545854610e-006
    -1.1035803155575678e-004 2.0952752203606181e-005
    -7.2600788482834914e-006 3.0886930796631743e-002
    -5.0144317270169004e-003 -1.4218361475375632e-002 1.</data></fund>
    </opencv_storage>
```

When I write only one instance of the structure, there is no problem with reading it, but when I'm trying to open the file presented above (which was saved by the code sample presented at the beginning of the post) the program crashes at the opening of that file:

```
else if (name == XML_CALIBSTRUCT)
    {
        QString filename = xml.readElementText();

        cv::FileStorage fsCal(filename.toStdString(), cv::FileStorage::READ);
```

Comment: Have You tried to save it using [cv::FileStorage](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/xml_yaml_persistence.html)? You could check what is the difference between xml produced that way and Yours.

Comment: Actually yes, the file I pasted was saved using cv::FileStorage method.

Comment: If `xml.writeTextElement` is a wrapper around cv::FileStorage, then You should post its code. In the question You said that the file pasted was generated by Your code, but now You say it is generated by cv::FileStorage. Clarify please.

Comment: I edited the post to clarify how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to encapsulate the instances of structure with `{` and `}`.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24201111/661211) is an answer to similar question with a link to some working code. Sorry for half-baked answer.