# Save vector <DMatch> in FileStorage

Tags: opencv, vector

I want to write a `vector<DMatch>` in a file. I checked that it’s possible write some vector of classes like Keypoints, Mat, etc, but it’s not possible with it. Anyone knows how can I do it? The section of code is the following:

```
Mat ImDescriptors;
Vector<KeyPoints> ImKeypoints;
FileStorage fs(Name, cv::FileStorage::WRITE);
fs <<” C” << "{";
fs << "Descriptors" << ImDescriptors;
fs << "Keypoints" << ImKeypoints;
fs << “}”;
```

It works ok, but when I add to this code the element:

```
Vector<DMatch> good_matches;
fs << “GoodMatches” << good_matches;
```

I get the following error:

```
c:\opencv248\build\include\opencv2\core\operations.hpp(2713): error C2665: 'cv::write' : any of the 9 overloads could convert all the argument types.
```

Comment: Have you read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24193717/how-to-write-vectordmatch-to-filestorage

Comment: Yes, I'm so sorry, I forgot to say that this section of code is inside in a 'for' loop, because I'm working with a vector of Mat (images). Because of this, I tried with this code:

 `fs << "Good_Matches" << "{" ;
  for (int e=0; e< si; e++)
  {
   fs << "distance" << good_matches[e].distance << "imgIdx" << good_matches[e].imgIdx << "queryIdx" << good_matches[e].queryIdx << "trainIdx" << good_matches[e].trainIdx;
  }
  fs << "}`

When later I open the Filestorage to read it, I get the following error: OpenCV error: Parsing error (File.xml): Duplicated key